# Interpreting probability densities in atomic orbitals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atoms, superposition

I once read that an atomic orbital can be conceptualised as a cloud of "electron-ness". That is, the electron literally *is* the cloud, and the probability density only relates to the probability of the electron interacting with another particle (say, a photon) at any given point in space.

This metaphor is fairly intuitive and got me through an undergrad course in physics and chemistry without issue. Yet I often read the caveat "the electron is not actually 'smeared out' across the probability distribution" with no evidence for why that is the case.

Is there an experiment/observation/result that disqualifies this interpretation in some circumstances?

Comment: Not an answer, of course, but I would be careful about ["reifying our successful abstractions"](http://www.ehu.eus/aitor/irakas/mes/Reference/mermin.pdf). An electron is not literally a cloud. Some might say an electron is literally an excitation of a quantum field, but I would call that reifying a successful abstraction, too. I'm not sure that we can ever say what an electron really *is*, because, well, it's whatever it is. Conceptual models of what things "are" are only useful to the extent that they aid our calculations and such. (I'm not totally a philosophical pragmatist, though.)

Comment: Can you cite a source for the claim that *the electron is not actually smeared out across the probability distribution*? While I take march's point about taking mathematical models too seriously I would guess most physicists would take the view that the electron **is** smeared out. The electron has no precise position, well not unless it's in a position eigenstate and those are unphysical anyway.

Comment: @JohnRennie It depends on what "smeared out" really means

Comment: @AaronStevens yes, and I agree with your interpretation that it means the electron does not have *any* location i.e. asking what the electron position is constitutes a meaningless question (at least I think that's what your answer says). But we need to say what the sources the OP refers to say in order to answer the OP's question definitively.

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes I am saying asking what the electron's position is meaningless. I also agree that the source would be very useful. I would adjust my answer accordingly if needed.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I don't have a specific source for the "smeared out" comment but I believe it is a common misconception for people to assume an electron's properties (e.g. charge) are distributed proportionately across all non-zero parts of the wavefunction, and to be proven wrong.

Comment: The textbook description is that an electron is behaves like a wave (given by its wave function) and when it interacts with another system (say, a photon) it "collapses the wavefunction" and the electron acts like a particle with a definite position. The wavefunction's modulus squared gives the probability of finding that point-like electron at any given point.

Comment: It is easier and more intuitive to interpret the electron as a wave all of the time and the probability density from squaring the modulus would be the probability the electron will interact with another system at a given point. So if a photon interacts with an electron at point A, it is interacting with *the entire wavefunction*. All of the properties of the electron would appear to be localised at point A, but in fact the electron "is" the wave and has not become a particle at all.

This is not what is taught and I wonder if it is incorrect in some cases, or just an alternative view?

Answer (score 1):

I think what we mean when we say that the electron is not smeared out is the following. "Smeared out" means that some of the electron is over here, and some of it is over there (like smearing out a ball of cream cheese on your bagel). Instead, according to some interpretations, the electron doesn't have *any* defined location (with uncertainty) until the interaction you mention at the beginning of your question.

So saying the electron is not smeared out is not going against the wavefunction/field picture. Rather, it is going against incorrect interpretations of the wavefunction/field picture by just saying the electron is not located "everywhere" in this "cloud".

Comment: One could add that the electron is considered to be a "point" particle w/o underlying structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to stress that it's wrong to think only of "probability
density". A wave function (an "orbital" in chemical jargon) carries more information than just its modulus squared. Generally speaking it's a complex function and its being complex *has physical meaning*.

As an instance consider $2p$ wavefunctions for hydrogen atom. There are three independent. Although chemists' use is to consider $2p_x$, $2p_y$, $2p_z$ in physics eigenfunctions of $L_z$ ($z$-component of angular momentum) are more important. Their expressions are
$$\eqalign{
    m=+1:\ & f(r)\,\sin\theta\,e^{i\phi} \cr
    m=0:\ &g(r)\,\cos\theta \cr
    m=-1:\ & f(r)\,\sin\theta\,e^{-i\phi} \cr}$$
You can see that as far as modulus is concerned the $m=+1$ and $m=-1$ eigenfunctions are identical. Yet they represent different states.

Another example: if you only looked at modulus square (the "electron cloud") you could know nothing about momentum. E.g. its expectation value is zero if $\psi$ is real, but may be not zero if $\psi$ is complex.

Comment: Thank you. I only mentioned position because I thought it was the only property relevant to my example but I am aware all information about the particle in encoded in the wavefunction.

Interesting that the m=0 expression is even while the others are odd (unless g(r) is also odd?). My understanding was that the "p-orbitals" used by chemists were derived from some linear combination of these expressions, resulting in 3 equivalent, non-complex shapes that together form a spherically symmetric set. As I type this out I realise how off base that might be though.